# How do I burn Ubuntu to DVD? errors on Mac and PC

Tags: windows, mac

Trying to make a Ubuntu 12.10 boot CD.

On my PC - The selected disc image file isn't valid.

On my macbook - (not recognized)

Comment: Make sure that .iso file you downloaded

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Windows, the cause was a problem in the .iso file downloaded. Verify your .iso file has the correct checksum, the list of correct checksums is in [UbuntuHashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) page.

If you are on a Windows box, you can use [winmd5](http://www.winmd5.com/) utility to get your downloaded .iso checksum. If on Linux, use md5sum command line utility.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the source you are downloading from is legitimate.

   Tell us more about the s/w you are using to "Burn" the DVD/CD

   Some problems have been observed over the past - year in my lab when creating a USB stick from the iso file from Windows.. I would however, recommend using a USB stick.

Comment: 1. From the Ubuntu site.

2. Disk Utility and the built in windows .iso viewer "right click burn to disc"

3. I'll look more into that. My macbook is from 2007 and I don't
think it supports usb boot.